# Laravel ORM call relationship in scope function

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to load a relationship from my customer table into my orders table but every time I try I keep getting this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   Call to a member function where() on a non-object

Here is my model for the orders

```
class Orders extends Eloquent
{
    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function order_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Order_item');
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Customer', 'id', 'customer_id');
    }

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Client', 'id', 'client_id');
    }

    public function billingAddress()
    {
        if($this->client()->first() != null)
        {
            return $this->client()->getBillingAddress($this->billing_address_id);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->customer()->getBillingAddress($this->billing_address_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my customer model

```
class Customer extends Eloquent
{
    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function order()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Orders');
    }

    public function addresses()
    {
        $this->hasMany('Customeraddress', 'id', 'customer_id');
    }

    public function scopeGetBillingAddress($query, $addressId)
    {
        return $this->addresses()
                    ->where('id', '=', $addressId)
                    ->where('type', '=', 'billing');
    }

    public function scopeGetShippingAddress($query, $addressId)
    {
        return $this->addresses()
                    ->where('id', '=', $addressId)
                    ->where('type', '=', 'shipping');
    }
}
```

And finally here is my customeraddress model:

```
class Customeraddress extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "customer_addresses";
    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function customer()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Customer');
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to run this on my controller to get the order address but I keep getting errors. How would I be able to do that via Eloquent relationship and scope function?

```
$address = Orders::find(21)->billingAddress()->first();
echo $address->street;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this one:

```
public function addresses()
{
    // $this->hasMany('Customeraddress', 'id', 'customer_id'); // wrong order of keys
    return $this->hasMany('Customeraddress', 'customer_id', 'id');
}
```

and these two

```
// edit: Order is a child of customer and client so:
public function customer()
{
    //return $this->hasOne('Customer', 'customer_id', 'id');
    return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'customer_id', 'id'); // customer_id and id are redundant bu I leave it for clarity
}

public function client()
{
    //return $this->hasOne('Client', 'client_id', 'id');
    return $this->belongsTo('Client', 'client_id', 'id'); // same here
}
```

And by the way, this one is dangerous :)

```
public function billingAddress()
{
    // This line results in db query everytime you call billingAddress 
    // Unless you cache the query, it's overkill
    if($this->client()->first() != null)

    // instead use:
    if($this->client != null)

    {
        return $this->client()->getBillingAddress($this->billing_address_id);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->customer()->getBillingAddress($this->billing_address_id);
    }
}
```

change scopes to accessors:

```
public function getBillingAddressAttribute($addressId)
{
    return $this->addresses()
                ->where('id', '=', $addressId)
                ->where('type', '=', 'billing')->first();
}

public function getShippingAddressAttribute($addressId)
{
    return $this->addresses()
                ->where('id', '=', $addressId)
                ->where('type', '=', 'shipping')->first();
}

// then you can call it like $customer->shippingAddress etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see what you mean about calling the first() in the billingAddress and I have removed that. But I still have a problem if I swap the keys around like you state I get this error now:
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clients.client_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `clients` where `clients`.`deleted_at` is null and `clients`.`client_id` = 21 limit 1)

With the previous way I can see that when I call $this->addresses() it returns me the values as if I called get() or first() which I didn't. Won't let me stack after $this->addresses()

Comment: show your customers and cients foreign keys. Where do you call $this->addresses()?

Comment: My customers and clients don't have foreign keys, they are the parents. The customeraddress and clientaddress have got foreign keys to their respective parents. So a client would have many customeraddresses thus why the hasMany('Customeraddress'). So table wise, the customer_address table has a foreign key called "customer_id" and customer only has a primary key "id".

Comment: Then the relation on Order should be inverted like in my edit. hasOne and belongsTo are relations with opposite directions, so if Client hasOne (or Many) SomeModel, then SomeModel belongsTo the Client

Comment: And I suggest sticking to laravel naming conventions, which are: Model (singular), ModelsController (plural), models table (plural) as it makes defining relations and many other things easier

Comment: Thank you deczo, but still no luck. I kept the relationships as you stated but I get this ([screenshot](http://www.chill-it.co.za/laravel_screenshot.jpg)). I think the problem is in the scope function as it doesn't let me stack my where in it. I did stick to the laravel conventions. I couldn't use the name Order for my class though as it wouldn't let me, so I had to make it plural but all my models are singular and controllers plural :-)

Comment: OK, the problem is with scopes not relations here - tbh I didn't notice that :/ scopes are for querying self (the model itself) not relations, so instead use accessors like in my edit

Comment: Thank you. I did consider an accessor but when I try to run this query, it fails:

$address = Orders::find(21)->billingAddress()->first();
echo $address->street;

By telling me Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::billing_address(). I even added a protected $appends. I think we are getting close to the answer but it just is getting stuck at some level

Comment: I finaly figured it out. I was trying to chain it the wrong way. But your answers helped a lot. I created a scope in the Customeraddress model as $this->addresses() returns customer addresses and in there I can filter the proper address. I tried now and it works. Thank you very much for the help. I will accept your answer as it drove me to the solution. Thanks again.